# Youtube t= URL parameter and 'seekTo' API function not quite accurate

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I've noticed that when you use the `t` URL parameter to start a video at a specific time, or the `seekTo` function in the Javascript API, the video will sometimes actually start a second or two before the specified time.

Any ideas why this is, or for a site that demands accurately seeking, workarounds other than a kinda hacky hide the element, mute the video, and poll for the current time until the actual start time is reached approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key frames.  The underlying Flash player can only seek to the nearest key frame.  You are at the mercy of the key frame spacing throughout the movie which in my experience is typically about 3 seconds apart for what I've seen on YouTube.   I went through the exact same research when I was trying to cue movies to the exact second.  I did a bunch of forum posting and got the bad news that there's nothing you can do about it, at least as far as my research took me.